# Regex expression for excluding the letters inside [ ] (square brackets)

Tags: regex

I am trying to find the VALUE out of a KEY PAIR VALUE using a regular expression. VALUE can have [ ] (square bracket). If [ ] (square bracket) is present in the VALUE then I want to extract only the characters present outside [ ].

So target string could be as follows:

```
   key="val"  or  key="[val_notRequired1]val"  or  key="[val_notRequired1][val_notRequired2]val"
```

pattern that I initially used:

```
key=("[^"]*"|'[^']*')
```

which extracts all the characters inside `" "`. So I tried by adding a non-capturing group `(?:[\[][^*][\]])` to my pattern to escape the special characters `[` `]`. But the result is still the same. Am I close ??

How can I extract only `val` in all the cases??
I am using regex in javascript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this:

```
key="(?:\[.*?\])*(.*?)"
```

it looks for key=" then any number of blocks that look like [...], and captures the remainder of the string.

See http://regexr.com/3cse1 for this in effect. You can hover over the items to see the capture of "val" each time.

Comment: Chris, was not the regex supposed to ignore whatever comes within square brackets inside the value part of the key-value pair ? Isn't your regex including them inside the match as well ?

Comment: The first bracket is a non-capturing group. Only the second bracket captures. It could be rewritten with lookbehinds and lookaheads, but this is normally the simplest approach.

Comment: What I say is just the outcome of looking into the link you shared. There all the whole 3 strings are being matched. I was expecting the non-capturing group not be to captured.

Comment: Hover your mouse over each match, and you'll see "Group #1: val"

Comment: All right. I am just used to having the matches only being selected, at regexr. Sorry.

Comment: Not really better. In your version, the matching group in the 3rd line is "[val_notRequired2]val"

Comment: It worked.                                                                                                      I found a online regex tester [link](https://regex101.com) `regex101.com` which  shows match information and explains your regex pattern bit by bit. Might help others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, depending on the context in which you are doing this, you could just `replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '')` - then whatever is left is `val`.

```js
key = "[val_notRequired1][val_notRequired2]val";

val = key.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '');
console.log(val);
```